# Remove the chapter number in the toc for glossaries?

Tags: glossaries, xindy

I am using Xindy to generate various glossaries. I am trying to remove the chapter number in front of the title of the glossaries. I coulnd not find any help in the package document. Does anyone know the exact command ?
[image: exemple of chapter number in the toc]

Thanks a lot in advance ! :)

```
\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype , title={Liste des acronymes}, toctitle={Liste des acronymes}]     
\printglossary[type=notation,title=Glossaire,toctitle=Glossaire]
\printglossary[type=notation,title={Liste des symboles}, toctitle={Liste des symboles}]
```

Comment: Adding a toc entry with the right format is easy.  Getting rid of the one created by \printglossary will be much more difficult.

Comment: Hm, what do you think `numberedsection` is designed for? ;-)